# Flutter - how to set the cros axis count to dynamic in gridview flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gridview

What I want to achieve is to dynamically change the crosAxisCount in gridview and set it according to the width of the widget.

I mean according to width of the widgets inside the gridview. If the widgets are long and only two can fit in the row then crosAxisCount = 2, if the widgets are small and four can fit in a row than crosAxisCount = 4.

Comment: You want to cross axis count depend on your screen size suppose you are in normal mode then display 3 grid and you are in portrait mode it display the 4-5 grid?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I mean according to the widgets inside the gridview. If the widgets are long and only two can fit in the row then crosAxisCount = 2, if the widgets are small and four can fit in a row than crosAxisCount = 4.

Comment: Did you tried with this?. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: @DholaHardik I am already using StaggeredGridView, but I don't know how to have dynamic crossAxisCount

Answer (score 0):

//// You should use staggered grid view. By using that you can achive what you want. Just refer below dart plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

```
    new StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        crossAxisCount: , //as per your requirement
        itemCount: , //as per your requirement
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if (index % 2 == 0) { //for even row
            return; //your required widget 
          } else { //for odd row
            return; //your required widget 
          }
        },
        staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => index % 2 == 0
            ? new StaggeredTile.fit(2)
            : new StaggeredTile.fit(1),
      )
```

Comment: I am already using StaggeredGridView, but I don't know how to have dynamic crossAxisCount

Comment: i need main axis count as dynamic can anyone help

Comment: i dont need only for even specific size for all according to their size